# Where can I find an estimate of my LinkedIn network size?

Tags: linkedin

Earlier, it was possible to see how big is your network (like circa 10,000 people up to 3rd degree). Now, I am not able to get this information.

Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LinkedIn Network Statistics Link](http://www.linkedin.com/network?trk=hb_tab_net) will give you an estimate of your first, second and third degree connections laid out like so:
[image]

LinkedIn no longer officially supports network statistics, and according to [this article](http://booleanblackbelt.com/2011/01/do-you-really-know-the-size-of-your-linkedin-network/#.UXp4vbWG18E) the statistics themselves were never accurate, per se (evidence includes network sizes precipitously dropping, and second and third degree connections *decreasing* with the addition of first degree connections).

This article, [How to Find Your LinkedIn Network Statistics](http://booleanblackbelt.com/2013/04/how-to-find-your-linkedin-network-statistics/) also gives alternatives for finding, estimating and visualizing your network size.

If you enter an asterisk into the search bar which will give you the number of results through which you are searching in your network.

[image]

This will also return your number of second degree connections, displayed further down the left-hand navigation bar:

[image]

Comment: +1 thanks a lot! Maybe you should also include the key information from the linked article: that one has to use your link,because it is no longer available directly, because linkedIn says the information is not reliable. However I am not sure I understand it correctly. Please complete your answer and I will accept.

Comment: @Tomas I'm not sure I fully understand the LinkedIn rationale behind no longer supporting network statistics, but I did add the article's second (more reliable) method for finding out your number of second degree connections. No need to accept if I'm not getting it right, but the asterisk method should, at least, be helpful.